# Property 'X' does not exist on type '{} | ITyped' when defining multiple types of an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an api that return an object with values or an empty object sometimes.

```
export interface IGeneratedViews {
  lastViewGenerationInfo: ILastViewGenerationInfo | {};
  generatedViews: IGeneratedView[];
}
```

When I try to use object in `ts` or `html` file I get this warning

```
this.generatedViews.lastViewGenerationInfo.executionStatus
```

`Property 'executionStatus' does not exist on type '{}'.`

I understand the error , but how I can skip it ?

The only way that I see is to use brakets

```
this.generatedViews.lastViewGenerationInfo['executionStatus']
```

And then add secularization using `if / ngIf` blocks

Comment: Can't you define it as just `lastViewGenerationInfo: ILastViewGenerationInfo`?

Comment: yes I could but I was making some API simulations using `rxjs` with an empty value `{}` ( because the futur API could send this value also ) so then VSCode shows me an alert because of wrong typing ( `{} is not a type of ILastViewGenerationInfo`)

Comment: Can you simply remove | {} from type declaration

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try catch block around the code with the error

```
try{

  //code that causes an error

}catch(e){
  functionToHandleError(e);
}
//continue from here
```

But you should only do that if the error is a known condition/unavoidable problem with an external library or only happens on bad user input. You shouldn't use it to allow the program to keep running at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what value you expect as a result if lastViewGenerationInfo is an empty object.

I would define a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (also known as [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)) to differentiate between `ILastViewGenerationInfo` and `{}` cases, and use a ternary operator to handle both cases

```ts
function isILastViewGenerationInfo(lgi: ILastViewGenerationInfo | {}): lgi is ILastViewGenerationInfo {
  return (lgi as ILastViewGenerationInfo).executionStatus !== undefined;
}

const executionStatus1: ExecutionStatus = isILastViewGenerationInfo(generatedViews.lastViewGenerationInfo) ? generatedViews.lastViewGenerationInfo.executionStatus : ExecutionStatus.DONE;
const executionStatus2: ExecutionStatus | undefined = isILastViewGenerationInfo(generatedViews.lastViewGenerationInfo) ? generatedViews.lastViewGenerationInfo.executionStatus : undefined;
```

As mentioned in the comments under OP, encoding lack of value with an empty object is a bit non-idiomatic, I would consider transforming the received object as a 2nd approach.